# HyperV VM was stopped - How to find why and when in Windows Server event logs

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, logging, event-viewer

Recently I keep finding a HyperV VM (the MSSP's vulnerability scanner) that is in the "Stopped" state when it shouldn't be and want to find the cause. I'm a support officer slowly transitioning to sysadmin and not very familiar with Windows logs yet. I can't find anything in the event viewer that would suggest why it stopped. How do I search/filter for this event for a specific VM?

It's worth adding that the VM is Qualys running on Ubuntu.

Comment: general comment that may not have anything to do with the issue:  Make sure Ubuntu Power Management for all plans is set to Never.  You need to set for all plans or the VM will stop. (Hyper-V or VMware - I use both).